Build fails because Main actor-isolated property 'mainContext' can not be referenced from a non-isolated context
I am trying to make a build of my app with Xcode cloud, but an unknown error popped to me that I don't really understand: Main actor-isolated property 'mainContext' can not be referenced from a non-isolated context.
this comes from my @main file, and sends me to this part of my code:
private func setupWorkoutHistoryManager() {
        if workoutHistoryManager == nil {
            workoutHistoryManager = WorkoutHistoryManager(modelContext: container.mainContext)
        }
    }

in the same file, I use this function like this for both my root view and welcomes screens:

Everything works fine on the simulator, this is the only error of my build which prevent me to export it.

Sounds like setupWorkoutHistoryManager is not isolated to the main actor. Make it @MainActor and it should work I think. Can't say for certain without a [mre] though.

yea it fixed it! thanks :))
